# Trying to redirect all .htaccess entries, only succeding with some

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file:

```html
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*shiftlistreport)$ index.php?page=reports&subpage=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*skiftlisteoversikt)$ index.php?page=reports&subpage=shiftlistreport [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 5 years"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

which isn't really working as I want it to work. I need the `.shiftlistreport-rules` to redirect, but if I put the `^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]` before those, the redirect in the that rule works, but none of the others.
if I move the above line below the other rules, the redirection works, but CSS and JS are not pulled from their directories (css and script, respectively).

How can I achive what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^(.*)$` regex literally matches **everything**, so you need to add some conditions to prevent it from matching stuff like css requests. Note that a `RewriteCond` only affects the *immediately following `RewriteRule`*, so you need to either duplicate your conditions or move them accordingly:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*shiftlistreport)$ index.php?page=reports&subpage=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*skiftlisteoversikt)$ index.php?page=reports&subpage=shiftlistreport [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```